# Unable to generate route

Tags: php, symfony, routes

I have a helper to get in the view what is my current route, but this line always return me a "NULL":

I check with console route:debug and all routes are right. And my application works fine.

```
$currentRoute = $request->attributes->get('_route');
```

My helper works with other functions and I have Container injected.

Any idea?
Thanks.

Comment: I think the problem is with routes which have parameters. How can I get this routes?

Comment: For the parameters you can use `$routeParams = $request->attributes->get('_route_params');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope it will help you some way because I'm not Symfony2 expert - I'm showing you how it works in my case.

In my Symfony2 projects I have routes defined this way:

**routing.yml**

```
mnab_contact:
    resource: "@MnabContactBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /

mnab_projects:
    resource: "@MnabProjectsBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /

mnab_article:
    resource: "@MnabArticleBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /
```

and for example for my ArticleBundle my routing.yml file is:

```
default:
    pattern:  /{anything}
    defaults: { _controller: MnabArticleBundle:Default:index , anything: null}
    requirements:
      anything: .*
```

so as you see I also use parameters.

For my projects I have routing.yml :

```
projects:
    pattern:  /projects/{anything}
    defaults: { _controller: MnabProjectsBundle:Default:index, anything: ''}
    requirements:
      anything: .*
```

And in both controllers I have code like that:

```
<?php

namespace Mnab\ArticleBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

use \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;


use \Mnab\Symfony\BaseController;

use \Mnab\DB\DbInterface;


class DefaultController extends BaseController
{
    public function indexAction(Request $request, $anything)
    {

        echo $request->attributes->get('_route');
        die();

    }
}
```

for both controller I have displayed either `projects` or `default` depending on url. Route names are being taken from `routing.yml` files from each Bundle directory.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help, I used this and this works fine when I have a simple route. But when I have a route with {anything} I get always NULL.

Comment: What you place as anything? For example my site (on localhost) is at `http://mnab` and when I run the following url: `http://mnab/weruiwreiuiudsf/wrerewwre` (so anything is `weruiwreiuiudsf/wrerewwre`). I can of course display `$anything` value in this controller simple `echo $anything;` Do you also get `$anything` value in this case? And probably the most important - do you use it simple in Controller or in Helper? (I haven't used Helpers so far)

Comment: I'm using this in a Helper, not in a Controller. I get NULL only some routes, not in all, I don't understand why. ¿Do you know how can I get the current route in my view in php?

Comment: You should check if route in Controller works fine and if so, pass it somehow to your Helper